# Dynamically added tooltip in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to achieve the following in Angular2 with Typescript:
I would like to have a Directive/Component which represents a tooltip. I know how to do this, so there is not the issue. I want to be able to add the tooltip to any HTML element on my page. This is also not a big issue. I could use a similar approach like [this one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html).

But now I have the following situation:
I have already components, which are dynamically loaded (i.e. forms with buttons, input fields etc.). But now say I want to have one of those components to have a tooltip. I could add a tooltip directive or component to all of their HTML templates, but this seems to be not a very clean solution to me. I.e. if I imagine that I might have multiple of those smaller Directives/Components which could be added to another component. Then I would need to add all of those Directives/Components to all the Components I might at some point use them on, and that seems messy.
I can configure these form components and also could expand the configuration, so the best would be to have an optional tooltip configuration for each component and if this is set, then the tooltip is dynamically added.

But I have no idea how I could achieve that without packing all those components in some other component which can dynamically create tooltips like in the approach I linked above.

So my question is: How could this be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

your directive selector should be like 'cool-button : not(a)'. if so, the component which are having class 'cool-button' will start work automatically. Once you r ready with your directive please register that at root component or root module. Use this directive name as an property at the

Comment: I am sorry, but I fear there is some part in your answer missing. Also: could you please explain how to use a directive to add components dynamically? From the documentation this seems to be not working as you can't have a factory in a directive.